# JS calculator, respecting order of operations

Tags: javascript, calculator, ecmascript-6, math-expression-eval

I have a function that receives an array of numbers and operations

```
Ex: userEntry = [3,+,3,x,3] -> returns 12
```

It is a calculator that adheres to the proper order of operations, therefore multiply/divide behaves differently than addition/subtraction. I have one redundant line of code:

```
userEntry = calculatorOperations
    .calculationSequence(operationsMD[i], indexOfOperand, userEntry);
```

is similar to:

```
 userEntry = calculatorOperations
    .calculationSequence(userEntry[1], indexOfOperand, userEntry);
```

With different behavior between operations, is it possible to remove this redundant line or is it neccesary?

```
function operateOnEntry(userEntry) {
//this is where the calculations occur when hitting =
const operationsMD = ['x', '/'];
let indexOfOperand;
let operation;

while (userEntry.includes('x') || userEntry.includes('/')) {
    let i = 0;
    if (!userEntry.includes('x')) {
        i++;
    }
    indexOfOperand = userEntry.indexOf(operationsMD[i]);
    userEntry = calculatorOperations
        .calculationSequence(operationsMD[i], indexOfOperand, userEntry);
}
while (userEntry.includes('+') || userEntry.includes('-')) {
    indexOfOperand = 1;
    userEntry = calculatorOperations
        .calculationSequence(userEntry[1], indexOfOperand, userEntry);
}
return userEntry;
}

let calculatorOperations = {
'x': (arg1, arg2) => {
    return arg1 * arg2;
},
'/': (arg1, arg2) => {
    return arg1 / arg2;
},
'+': (arg1, arg2) => {
    return arg1 + arg2;
},
'-': (arg1, arg2) => {
    return arg1 - arg2;
},
returnIndexOfEntry: (index, userEntry) => {
    let arg1 = Number(userEntry[index - 1]);
    let arg2 = Number(userEntry[index + 1]);
    return [arg1, arg2];
},
returnSpliced: (index, newTotal, userEntry) => {
    userEntry.splice((index - 1), 3, newTotal);
    return userEntry;
},
calculationSequence: (operation, indexOfOperand, userEntry) => {

    let getArgs = calculatorOperations.returnIndexOfEntry(indexOfOperand, userEntry);
    let newTotalForEntry = calculatorOperations[operation](getArgs[0], getArgs[1]);
    let newUserEntry = calculatorOperations.returnSpliced(indexOfOperand, newTotalForEntry, userEntry);
    return newUserEntry;
}
};
```

Comment: `operationsMD` seems superfluous. If a `x` or `/` is found in `userEntry`, well there it is. Why have a separate array for these operators - and then only these operators.

Comment: *is it possible to remove this redundant line*  Not as long as there are separate loops for multiplication and addition. Perhaps extract a while loop to it's own function and pass the operator set you're looking for. That is pass `operationsMD = ['x', '/']` and then pass `operationsMD = ['+', '-']`

Comment: @radarbob Please don't edit the code just to adjust whitespace. Please refer to answers to [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/762/120114) for reasoning.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ, good point given this is `Code Review`.  FWIW indenting misalignment is most often the annoying nature of writing code blocks here. As for moving that `if` to a 1-liner, I beg mercy from the court.

Comment: @radarbob what court...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Question

> With different behavior between operations, is it possible to remove this redundant line or is it neccesary?

Yes you can iterate over the operations using [`Object.keys(calculatorOperations)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), since the functions are listed in order of highest precedence first:

```
Object.keys(calculatorOperations).forEach(function(functionName) {
  while(userEntry.includes(functionName)) {
    indexOfOperand = userEntry.indexOf(functionName);
    userEntry = calculatorOperations
      .calculationSequence(functionName, indexOfOperand, userEntry);
  }
});
```

Though be aware that all keys will be iterated over, including `returnIndexOfEntry`, `returnSpliced` and `calculationSequence`. If you didn't want those to be iterated over, the functions for the four mathematical operations could be moved into a sub-property and those could be iterated over instead, or else move the other helper functions out of the object.

With this approach, there is no need for the variable `operationsMD`.

### Other feedback

- As a default, use `const` for variables. When you determine that it needs to be re-assigned (especially for loop interators/counters) then use `let`. So variables like `calculatorOperations`,  `getArgs`, `newUserEntry`, etc. can be declared with `const`
- As [@FreezePhoenix](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/168361/freezephoenix) mentioned, arrow functions that only have one line in the body don't need to be surrounded by braces. For example, the calculation for times:

  > ```
  > 'x': (arg1, arg2) => {
  >   return arg1 * arg2;
  > },
  > ```

  Can be simplified to:

  ```
  'x': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 * arg2,
  ```
- Presumably the inconsistencies with the indentation are due to the pasting here but make sure you always use the same amount of indentation (e.g. two or four spaces).

### Updated code

See code updated per recommendations below.

```js
function operateOnEntry(userEntry) {
  let indexOfOperand;
  let operation;
  Object.keys(calculatorOperations).forEach(function(functionName) {
    while (userEntry.includes(functionName)) {
      indexOfOperand = userEntry.indexOf(functionName);
      userEntry = calculationSequence(functionName, indexOfOperand, userEntry);
    }
  });
  return userEntry;
}
const returnIndexOfEntry = (index, userEntry) => {
  const arg1 = Number(userEntry[index - 1]);
  const arg2 = Number(userEntry[index + 1]);
  return [arg1, arg2];
};
const returnSpliced = (index, newTotal, userEntry) => {
  userEntry.splice((index - 1), 3, newTotal);
  return userEntry;
};
const calculationSequence = (operation, indexOfOperand, userEntry) => {
  const getArgs = returnIndexOfEntry(indexOfOperand, userEntry);
  const newTotalForEntry = calculatorOperations[operation](getArgs[0], getArgs[1]);
  const newUserEntry = returnSpliced(indexOfOperand, newTotalForEntry, userEntry);
  return newUserEntry;
}
const calculatorOperations = {
  'x': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 * arg2,
  '/': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 / arg2,
  '+': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 + arg2,
  '-': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 - arg2
};
var userEntry = [3, '+', 3, 'x', 3];
console.log(operateOnEntry(userEntry));
```

Comment: Am I allowed to edit my answer in response to yours?...

Comment: I think so- maybe just give credit, if you don’t mind ;)

Comment: Will this do: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/204864/revisions?

Comment: Yes- “_Great minds_...”

Comment: *"... think alike."* ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Overview

- If you are using ES6, you should use the full ability of arrow functions: `(args) => returnVal`
- In addition, some of the methods don't need to be defined as a property.
- `calculatorOperations` should be a constant.
- You don't need to access each element in an array like this: `(getArgs[0], getArgs[1])`, you can do `(...getArgs)`
- I agree with [@SamOnela](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/s%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%8d-on%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%8c%e1%b4%80) in that you can iterate over the operations. However, their method pollutes global namespace

## Questions

- Why are you using `x` not `*`?

## Rewrite

```js
    function operateOnEntry(userEntry) {
        let indexOfOperand,
            operation;
        Object.keys(calculatorOperations.ops).forEach(function(functionName) {
            while (userEntry.includes(functionName)) {
                indexOfOperand = userEntry.indexOf(functionName);
                userEntry = calculatorOperations.calculationSequence(functionName, indexOfOperand, userEntry);
            };
        });
        return userEntry;
    }
    
    const calculatorOperations = {
        ops: {
            'x': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 * arg2,
            '/': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 / arg2,
            '+': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 + arg2,
            '-': (arg1, arg2) => arg1 - arg2
        },
        returnIndexOfEntry(index, userEntry) {
            let arg1 = Number(userEntry[index - 1]),
                arg2 = Number(userEntry[index + 1]);
            return [arg1, arg2];
        },
        returnSpliced(index, newTotal, userEntry) {
            userEntry.splice((index - 1), 3, newTotal);
            return userEntry;
        },
        calculationSequence(operation, indexOfOperand, userEntry) {
    
            let getArgs = calculatorOperations.returnIndexOfEntry(indexOfOperand, userEntry),
                newTotalForEntry = calculatorOperations.ops[operation](...getArgs),
                newUserEntry = calculatorOperations.returnSpliced(indexOfOperand, newTotalForEntry, userEntry);
            return newUserEntry;
        }
    };
    var userEntry = [3, '+', 3, 'x', 3];
    console.log(operateOnEntry(userEntry));
```